# Why is zero treated as positive sign?

Tags: signal

In signed int or in binary digit

> Zero is treated as positive sign

and

> 1 is treated as negative sign.

For example :-

```
1000 0000 0000 0110 = -6 
0000 0000 0000 0110 =  6
```

But in pulse form 1 is treated as positive and 0 is as neutral.

```
         ---   ---   ---
         | |   | |   | |
---------   ---   ---   ---------
```

Why? Is there is a logic behind it.

And is it possible treat it in opposite way i.e 1 as positive sign and 0 as negative sign

Comment: Change the value in what?

Comment: can we assume 1 as positive and 0 as negative sign and can do some calculations on this assumption

Comment: A lot of what is pre-supposed by that question is simply not true in the first place.  Serial communications are not universally like that, and that is a ... ahem! ... rare way of encoding -6.

Comment: @JdeBP actually I put this example only for better understood, that i'am asking about sign not the magnitude and output.

Comment: Its not always treated as a negative.  It is the case, it is a negative, if your using 1's compliment.  Its not clear what you mean by "binary digit" exactly.  As for the reason this was choose it was a choice to make base 2 arithmetic easier for us as humans to do.  I think you mean "sign and magnitude" instead of "binary digit" but I can't be sure.

Comment: @JdeBP - What exactly is rare about it?  Its a signed integer. That example is 100% correct.

Comment: @Ramhound sir, If i do substraction between 5 and -15 then the machine convert it into binary form like 0000 0101=5 and       1000 1111= -15 and then do the calculation, here high order bit of 5 is 0 and it is treated as positve and high order bit of -15 is 1 and it is treated as negative and i'am asking that can we change this that 0 will represent negative and 1 will represent positive sign. Ans sorry for making more confusion.

Comment: @Ramhound It's correct for signed-magnitude. But signed-magnitude is indeed "extremely rare". Do you know of any reasonably current general-purpose architecture that uses  it?

Comment: @JamieHanrahan - You are of course right.

Comment: akash: Although 0000 0101=5, 1000 1111 does NOT equal -15 in two's complement. -15 in eight bits, two's complement notation, would be 1111 0001.

Comment: Why on earth did this question get three down-votes? If you don't know how signed integers are represented in computers - and my experience is that many people, even a significant fraction of developers these days, don't - signed-mag is a pretty common expectation.

Comment: I happily accept these down-votes to getting best answers for my queries. And all who down-voted my question, if there is any misunderstanding or any confusion in the question, then you can ask me, i'll clear my question by putting more edits and comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your initial assertion isn't really true, not for the vast majority of CPU architectures that are in anything like common use - which use "two's complement arithmetic".

In 2's complement arithmetic, if the high order bit is 1, that indicates a negative number; but if the high order bit is 0, that does not indicate a positive number. It indicates *non-negative*. The difference is subtle, but important. The number could be zero, or it could be positive.

In 2's complement, the number scale looks like this - I'll use eight-bit integers for simplicity:

```
binary   signed  unsigned
01111111  127      127
01111110  126      126
 ...
00000011    3        3
00000010    2        2
00000001    1        1
00000000    0        0
11111111   -1      255
11111110   -2      254
 ...
10000010 -126      130
10000001 -127      129
10000000 -128      128
```

To negate (arithmetically invert) a number in this system, i.e. multiply it by -1: you first invert all the bits, then add 1. So if we were to start with 1, and invert the bits, we'd get 11111110. Add 1, and we have 11111111. As above. Notice that if we do it again, we get back to 00000001, as we should.

Computers use this system because it makes the add, subtract, etc., arithmetic logic very simple: The same logic (simple binary adders; you just add all the bits, including the sign bits) works for both signed and unsigned numbers. Notice that adding 1 to any number on that scale gets you to the right answer... except in the overflow cases: Adding 1 to 127 results in -128, if you're interpreting the numbers as signed. But overflows and carries and so on are generally caught by either condition flags or exceptions.

It is a curious quirk of two's complement that we have one more negative number than we have positive.. as zero is neither negative nor positive. So with eight bits, signed, we can represent -128, but not +128. +127 is the highest positive number. This is not much of a problem.

A few historical computers (CDC 3000 and 6000 series, and some old Univac mainframes; I know of no contemporary examples) have been built that used "one's complement". In one's complement, to invert a number, you just flip the bits. This results in almost the same scale as above, except that the negative side goes from -127 to... -0! That's right, in one's comp. machines, you have two zeroes: Positive zero and negative zero. This makes the arithmetic generally more complicated. Negative zeroes are generally converted to positive at some point.

You're probably thinking it should be more like "signed magnitude", which is analagous to how we normally write numbers. e.g. -2 would be 10000002. You'll notice that adding 1 to that does not give you the correct signed magnitude representation for -1. It gives you -3 instead. This makes the arithmetic more complicated to do, which is why it isn't used.

Comment: this is what i'am searching for.. thank you :) +1

Answer (score 4):

This is actually fairly complicated. On one level, the answer is “because we need some standard”: if you make a new system, it’s far easier to make it the same way as old systems work, so that you can interact with those old systems more easily. However, in some of these cases, there are deeper reasons.

In this post, I will assume eight-bit integers. The principles should work the same when using a different number of bits.

***Electric Pulses***

Here, with only two values, it doesn’t matter which we call “zero” and which we call “one”. In fact, there’s no reason to call them “zero” and “one”. For example, [USB uses “J” and “K”](http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_3.htm), and some USB devices use the opposite convention as others for actually transmitting the signal.

***Integer encoding***

There are actually several ways to encode integers. The one you show in your question is called “signed magnitude”. It closely resembles how we write numbers in everyday life: we potentially have a minus sign, and then we write the number. In this case, the minus sign (or plus sign) is simply the value of the first bit.

However, not all numbers are signed. If I’m encoding the number of widgets my factory made today, I want to use an unsigned number (unless I sometimes destroy widgets in my factory). In that case, it would only be reasonable to let `0000 0110` mean I made six widgets that day.

If you’re using both signed and unsigned numbers, then it would be nice if converting between them were as easy as possible. It’s easier to convert if the same bits represent the same number in both cases, so we want `0000 0110` to mean six even if we use a signed integer. That leads to making a leading `1` be negative, and a leading `0` be positive.

***Two’s Complement***

Very few systems actually use signed magnitude for integers now, though. Signed magnitude has a number of problems, including both `0000 0000` and `1000 0000` meaning the same thing (zero). Instead, most represent signed integers using what’s called “two’s complement”. It represents positive numbers the same way (with a leading zero, and the other bits being as with unsigned numbers), but represents negative numbers differently. With unsigned eight-bit numbers, the most significant bit is the 128s place; with two’s complement eight-bit numbers, it’s the negative 128s place. Thus, `1000 0000` is negative 128, `1000 0001` is negative 128 + 1 = negative 127, all the way up to `1111 1111`, which is negative one.

This may seem like an odd way of representing signed integers, but it has a number of advantages over the more obvious signed-magnitude. For one thing, it gets rid of the problem I mentioned earlier of having two representations for zero. For another, you can just add the numbers using the same circuitry used for adding unsigned numbers, and it will work out correctly assuming there’s no overflow (and even if there is overflow, it’s easier to handle). That isn’t true with signed magnitude.

***Conclusion***

There are a number of possible ways to [represent signed numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations); signed magnitude and two’s complement are just two of the more popular ones. In one sense, it doesn’t matter which you use; you could theoretically invent your own method not listed there (or just use signed magnitude with the sign bit reversed) and make entire computers that use it. That would very likely not be a good idea though, because you’d need to convert to a different format if you wanted to share data with another computer. We could have ended up using signed-magnitude integers as our standard (as we did for [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Formats)), and then the best choice for most new computers would probably be to do the same thing. However, the choice wasn’t exactly arbitrary, and there are good reasons to make positive integers use a leading zero instead of a leading one (such as conformance with unsigned numbers).

Comment: [USB uses differential signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Signaling), in which the specific values aren't as important as the difference between them. This is more resistant to noise, at the expense of being slightly more complex.

Comment: I think that’s the case for a lot of standards, but I’m not sure. I usually pretend that the most basic level of a computer is assembly code and ignore the physical layer below that.

Comment: There are plenty of layers between physical and assembler. After all, assembler is just a convenient way of writing binary machine language code (Wikipedia even calls "symbolic machine code" basically a synonym). "Pure" assembler has a one-to-one mapping to the corresponding machine language. (Macro assemblers and others can have [quite advanced features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Support_for_structured_programming) that do not map directly to machine language constructs.)

Comment: Yeah, I know. I’ve written code in assembly (but not full programs). I know that macros get converted into pure assembly, which then has a bijection to the actual codes stored in the program executable (assuming it’s compiled to the physical machine code instead of JVM or something), which the CPU reads from RAM and executes. I mean that I ignore the details of how it gets stuff to/from RAM, how it executes instructions, how it connects to other parts of the computer, etc.

I usually do, anyway. I know a bit about how those work, but my practical hardware knowledge ends at “change a hard disk”

Answer (score 0):

It's an arbitrary standard for *signed* integers. Look at the smaller signed byte, where 00000000 through 01111111 are treated as positive integers, and the highest bit, when set, makes them negative, covering the range from -127 through 127 (base 10), with zero encoded either with leading bit set or not. The identical bit patterns *also* encode the *unsigned* numbers 0 through 255, so it's simply a standard that makes it possible for programmers to understand the work of others. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations for information on signed number representation.

You could invent your own standard for signed numbers, but that leads to confusion. In some languages, Boolean *True* is treated as 00000001, in other languages (e.g. VB) it's 10000001, and in yet others it's any value other than zero. That's just another pitfall to be wary of when translating program languages.

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't quite correct. You've described one's complement. All machines in common use use two's complement, in which there is no "negative zero".

Comment: You said it yourself: "All machines in common use", i.e. standards are arbitrary and can be changed.

Comment: True, but it's highly unlikely the OP will ever encounter a one's comp. machine (and thereby encounter a negative zero)... outside a computer museum, anyway. As far as I know, Seymour Cray designed the last general-purpose architectures that used one's complement (CDC 3000 and 6000 series, maybe the 7000) and even he went to two's complement with the Cray-1.

Comment: Read his question: "is it *possible* [to] treat it in opposite way i.e 1 as positive sign and 0 as negative sign."

Comment: +1 @DrMoishePippik for understanding my question

Comment: DrMoishe: All I'm saying is that in terms of any machine the OP is ever likely to encounter (outside of a computer museum or some very specialized architecture), zero is not "encoded either with leading bit set or not" (i.e. there is no negative zero), and the (for example) 8-bit range covers -12_8_ through +127. Are there other possibilities, theoretically? Sure.